# how to take the all places that a word exists on vim?

Tags: search, vim, cpu-word, show

for example i have the following text :

```
My eyes are red , but the red eyes doesn't mean nothing

Red will  always be red .

My best color is red!
```

i want vim to search and tell or show me all the spots that "red" word exists.

can vim do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/` to search forward in the file and `?` to search backwards in the file.

`n` goes to the next instance of your search text and `N` goes to the previous instance.

`:set hlsearch` turns on highlighted searching.

Example:

```
/red
```

Comment: Yes man your answer is the correct one because it isnt GUI...
I just had a test on my college that was asking for multiple search for a word and i was thinking that it might exists a setting-command that instant shows you all the words "highlighted" but then i learned alone for the "n" "N" use and then i figured out the answer :D!Thanks for help anyway...

Answer (score 1):

What about the standard search ?

```
:set ignorecase
:set hlsearch
:set incsearch
/red
```

Answer (score 0):

Type the following, verbatim into vim

```
 :set hlsearch <enter>
 /red <enter>
```

Answer (score 0):

in Vim:

In command mode: make sure you have set the highliting if you want your word to be highlited when searched: `:set hlsearch`.

Then go on top of the word you want, and press : `*` (in command mode) (multiple times, it will go from one to the next, and wrap around to the beginning. Nifty!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/red\c` to search forward and ignore case, or `?red\c` to search backward.

Or, move your cursor to "red", press `Ctrl+*` to go to the next instance. `Ctrl+#` goes to the previous instance.